# How does "noises" in computing convolution affect the model precision and the training speed?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, training, convolutional-layers, dropout

Consider the discrete convolution written in a matrix form, if a small amount $s$ of the zero entries (represented as white blocks) are deviated from zero, can the model precision or the training speed be increased? A "small" amount means, for example, $s \leq n$, where $n$ is the dimension of the matrix.
[image]

I guess this idea is similar to an inverse procedure of dropout/dilution, where a small amount of matrix entries are replaced by zero. Here, a small amount of zeros are replaced by some nonzero random values.

- As a newbie to AI, I am not familiar with many historic papers on the development of AI. Probably some researchers have already analyzed this several years ago.
  Any related papers or conference presentations are highly appreciated.

Comment: After even one training step you'll find that none of them are exactly zero. Maybe instead you should talk about adding some large noise to some random elements regardless of whether they are zero?

Comment: 1D convolutions are also fairly unusual. Are you really thinking of a 1D convolution, are you thinking of convolutional neural networks which are usually 2D, or are you thinking of a layer of a traditional dense neural network with the weights being a 2D matrix which is not a convolution?